# Не могу записать в файл второй раз

Tags: c#

При вызове второй раз функции возникает ошибка:

> Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу  .... так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

```
void Write()
{
    string writePath = @"tasksend.txt";
    DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
    try
    {
        string res;
        var result = MainWindow.modelDATABASE.tasks.Where(p => p.Логин == 
                    ApplicationViewModel.Login_aut_user).ToList().
        Where(p => p.Дата == date1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    //  StreamWriter sw;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(writePath, false, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
        {

            foreach (task i in result)
            {

            if (i.Status == 1) res = "Выполнена";
            else res = "Не выполнена";
            sw.Write("Название задачи->" + i.Название + '\n' +
            "Приоритет->" + i.Приоритет.ToString() + '\n' +
            "Периодичность" + i.Периодичность + '\n' +
            "Полное описание->" + i.Полное_описание + '\n' +
            "Статус->" + res + '\n' +
            "-------------------------------------------" + '\n'
                );


            }
        }
        //sw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Записано");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Откройте файл  string writePath = @"tasksend.txt"; вне функции Write() и передайте его туда. Закрывать не придется и создавать несколько раз тоже. Пользуйтесь чаще Dependency Injection в таких случаях.